# Exit Python thread based on flag

Tags: python, multithreading

Suppose inside run() method of a python Thread , I check a flag.If that flag is True , I assume my thread should exit has done it's job and should exit.

How should I exit the thread at that point ? Trying `Thread.exit()`

```
class  workingThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, flag):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.myName = Thread.getName(self)
        self.FLAG= flag
        self.start()    # start the thread

    def run(self) : # Where I check the flag and run the actual code

        # STOP
        if (self.FLAG == True):

                # none of following works all throw exceptions    
                self.exit()
                self._Thread__stop()
                self._Thread_delete()
                self.quit()

        # RUN
        elif (self.FLAG == False) :
               print str(self.myName)+ " is running."
```

Comment: How about just "return"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

korylprince is correct. You just need a return statement, or in your case pass:

```
def run(self):
    if self.FLAG == True:
        pass
    else:
        print str(self.myName) + " is running."
```

Since you have no looping structure in the code, the thread is going to terminate in both cases. Basically once the function returns the thread will exit. Add a loop of some kind in there if you want do more than one operation.

Answer (score 2):

I may typically use the following pattern:

```
def run(self):
    while self.active:
        print str(self.myName) + " is running."
```

It will exit automatically when `self.active` is `False`.

**Caution**: When using `while True:`, always be sure to structure your code to avoid it hogging the CPU-core, because it can easily do this.

Comment: How do you avoid hogging the CPU-core when you have a busy loop like this?

Comment: ...by making a blocking call and/or by using `time.sleep(0.01)`, etc.